# Converting a Mixed SUBSET-SUM Problem To All-Positive Case

Tags: subset-sum, polynomial-time-reductions

Let's say we have a SUBSET-SUM problem with list {$x_1,x_2,x_3,...x_N$} and weight $W$, with some of $x_i<0$. Is there a known way, in polynomial time, to convert this problem into an equivalent problem, but with all $x_i \geq 0$? And if there aren't any, is it possible for there to be such an algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both variants are NP-complete, so such a reduction surely exists: the [definition of NP-completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness#Formal_definition) guarantees it.

If you want an explicit reduction, you can reduce one to the other (reduce to 3SAT using Cook's theorem, then reduce 3SAT to the other using its NP-completeness).  The resulting reduction will be ugly, though, so I suspect this might not be what you're looking for.

If you want a simple and natural reduction, I'm not sure how to achieve it.